# Unable to change z-index for jquery.float.tooltip

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm using `jquery.flot.tooltip` plugin to show tool-tip for pie charts created through `jquery.flot.pie`, but when loading the pie-chart in a pop-up the tool-tips are showing in the background of the pop-up.

Can anyone help me how to change/set z-index for that tool-tip so that it will appear in the foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jquery.flot.tooltip` uses div with 'id' `flotTip` for rendering the floating tool-tip, adding css `z-index:10000` for that 'id' solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.tooltip).css('z-index',100000);
```

...